# Slow Google App Engine Extjs download or failure to download

Tags: google-app-engine, extjs

I have a simple app at http://menkyo-kaiden.appspot.com/.  It uses Extjs whose main library file ext-all.js is approximately 1 MB.

I've had the app up and running for 6 months no issues.  Today it won't download the Extjs library or takes over a minute to download.  I logged into App Engine admin and see no issues only Elevated status for Google Datastore which I'm not using.  App Engine admin shows my latency to be under 100ms which obviously isn't the case.

So is there an issue with App Engine today or something has been changed on Google's end?

Comment: This is certainly not a solution, but you can get ext-all.js from sencha cdn until this issue is properly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem has disappeared.  Perhaps an issue with my ISP throttling bandwidth.